# HP officejet prints partial pages

Tags: printing, hp

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and connected a HP Officejet 6600 with a USB cable. The printer almost always prints a half page followed by a number a partial pages. It is worst on multipage documents. I have upgraded to the latest HP-LIP. I ran HP-toolbox in a terminal and then the HP-LIP diagnostic and got the following results: Please not the 2 warning messages towards the bottom. Please help.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.5)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.5)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found

Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.5)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Latest version of HPLIP is already installed.

Checking for Dependencies....

---

### | SYSTEM INFO |

Kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Host: stewart-Pangolin-Performance
 Proc: 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 16.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

---

### | HPLIP CONFIGURATION |

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.16.5
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  16.04 version

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:

## hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.16.5

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.16.5
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.16.5
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d

## Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.

[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.16.5
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/usb/Officejet_6600?serial=CN3CM8RJN405RN"
printer_name = Officejet-6600
working_dir = .

[settings]
systray_visible = 1
systray_messages = 1

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/simple-scan %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = true
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list =

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address =

[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1467382612
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.16.5

[installation]
date_time = 08/04/2016 10:50:02
version = 3.16.5

---

### | COMPILEDEP |

gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               5.4.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -

---

### | General Dependencies |

libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.2           OK         -
 python-xml           Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.1.0           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -
 pil                  PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 pyqt4-dbus           PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               2.23            OK         -
 python-devel         Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.12          OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 python-dbus          Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.0           OK         -
 cups-ddk             CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit                       OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 reportlab            Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.3.0           OK         -
 pyqt4                PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 python2X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.12          OK         -
 python-notify        Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -

---

### | Scan Configuration |

scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.16.5          OK         -
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.16.5          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

---

### | External Dependencies |

gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.18            OK         -
 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.1.3           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.17.1          OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.25          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.10.6          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.6.32          OK         -

---

### | Python Extentions |

hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.16.5          OK         -
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.16.5          OK         -

---

### | DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |

device `hpaio:/usb/Officejet_6600?serial=CN3CM8RJN405RN' is a Hewlett-Packard Officejet_6600 all-in-one
device`hpaio:/net/officejet_6600?ip=192.168.1.4&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_6600 all-in-one

---

### | DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |

Device URI                        Model

---

hp:/usb/Officejet_6600?serial=CN  HP Officejet 6600
  3CM8RJN405RN

---

### | INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |

### HP-Officejet-6600

Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Officejet_6600?serial=CN3CM8RJN405RN
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Officejet-6600.ppd
**warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Officejet-6600.ppd ppd file
PPD Description:** 
Printer status: printer HP-Officejet-6600 is idle.  enabled since Thu 04 Aug 2016 10:34:57 AM EDT
Communication status: Good

---

### | PERMISSION |

USB             HP-Officejet-6600              Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/005' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'

Checking for Configured Queues....
**warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/HP-Officejet-6600.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/HP-**Officejet-6600.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check

Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Diagnose completed...

Comment: maybe it is a file permissions issue for ppd file